# Mongo 4 ChangeStreamDocument<POJO> fails to cast to Morphia POJO at runtime but compiles fine

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, morphia

I have a Mongo ChangeStream listener using a Consumer:

```
private final Consumer<ChangeStreamDocument<POJO>> log = el -> {
    LOG.info("{} deserialized Changestream Doc with wrapper: {}", this.collection, el.toString());
    LOG.info("{} actual document object: {}", this.collection, el.getFullDocument());

    // runtime exceptions on the following lines:
    LOG.info("{} class of document object: {}", this.collection, el.getFullDocument().getClass());
    LOG.info("{} id of POJO document as fetched through POJO getter: {}", this.collection, el.getFullDocument().getId());
  };
```

The version of the Mongo driver I'm using is `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.2.3`

Even though java successfully compiles this code (and assumes `.getFullDocument()` is returning a `POJO.class`, it fails during runtime with `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bson.Document cannot be cast to class ...POJO.class`.

The POJO's model is 1:1 with the document model. The only thing the POJO has is `Morphia` annotations (which I cannot work around), ie `@Entity(POJO.COLLECTION_NAME)`. Is there any clean way to have this deserialize properly? Especially since this is runtime, not compile time.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with that code. Could you share a bit more code/context? There's not enough there for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by recognizing why the POJOMapper from Mongo was not working.

The [POJOCodecProvider](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/codecs/pojo/PojoCodecProvider.html) enforces that all getters and setters have the same type. The Morphia model I'm working with unfortunately wraps some getters with an `Optional`. This breaks the POJO codec which forced me to define a custom codec for this type.

No type checking is enforced at compile type with the `ChangeStreamDocument<?>`